# How to start a schedule task whenever having a Queue message on the Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, message-queue

On my server, there will be a queue message whenever somebody submit a form on the website. The queue message is created under :

```
Server Manager\ Features\ Message Queueing\ Private Queues\FolderName\Queue message.
```

What I am trying to do is to create a scheduled Task under Task Scheduler and start this task whenever there is a queue under above place.

I know that I can trigger this task by

```
Triggers\New
Begin the task : On an event
Custom\ New Event Filter
```

And there are some option here. But the problem is, I don't see that queue message create any log or event under Event Viewer. Is there anyway to create or find out this information and link that to the task I want to schedule ?
Many thanks!

Comment: I tried this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726012(v=ws.10).aspx to find that queue event but cannot find. May be the private queue is not logged to the event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution for it. Instead of creating the scheduled task, I will create a trigger and a rule attached to it, under that message queue. Thanks for your attention and hope it helps you who have the same issue!